# Express and Node js - Can't redirect on error

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

So the thing is that I'm trying to catch a MySQL error, so when it happens I just want to redirect the user to another page of my app and display a notification or something, but doesn't matter what URL I put in the redirect method it sends me to the index page "/". This is my code, as you can see I even put Google URL, but it stills send me to home "/".

```
var query = "DELETE FROM buildings WHERE id = ?";
connection.query(query, id, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Foreign key restriction");
        return res.redirect("http://google.com");
    }
    if (fs.existsSync('./public/' + img)) {
        fs.unlinkSync('./public/' + img);
    }
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

Also is good to say that the "Foreign key restriction" is printed on console, but I'm not redirected.
Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried executing an query that returns and error?

Comment: Also, if you can change the second redirect to another URL asside from the aforementioned URLS. And see what happens.

Comment: I'm sure this query returns an error, because I want it to return it, if a do a console.log() inside the if(err) the message is displayed, but I'm not redirected

Comment: can you remove the return before res.redirect

Comment: I tried that already, but it doesn't work neither :(

Comment: can you try and hard code it this way `res.status(302).location("https://google.com").end()` and see what happens

Comment: Nope, still not working, I'm really running out of ideas :/

Comment: Please post the complete route handling code (i.e., the enclosing app.get() call). You are somehow overriding the redirect code.

Comment: Watch the `existsSync` query for race conditions. Best practices advise that you simply catch an error for `unlinkSync`.

Comment: Can you please drop full code snippet along with **route**.

Answer (score 1):

`err` never gets set so you always fallback and the last redirect to `/` is used.

You are missing a `[]` in your query call. I.e., it should be

```
connection.query(query, [id], function(err) {
```

Comment: Actually I made a console.log inside the if(err) and it gets there, I tried connection.query(query, [id], function(err) but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: if (err) {
        console.log("lol"); //this is actually printed in console
        return res.redirect("http://google.com");
    }

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are "returning" to the correct function. As in try to return your query first as so:

`return connection.query(query, id, function(err) {`

Comment: said in other words... the returning should be bubbled up all the way to the route/function using 'res' as an argument. i hope this works for you buddy!